# Is there another way to kill an app other than force quit?

Tags: macos, applications

My Excel is not force quitting, I can't find it in the Activity Monitor or the PID for it... Is there another way I could kill it?

[image]

Comment: How did you launch this particular activity monitor?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in either of those places, it's not running. It's probably just a ghost icon.

Try restarting your dock by opening Terminal and typing:

```
killall Dock
```